# application has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-listview

When I run my android application it gives an error "The application has stopped working,please try again". Please help me to solve this problem. i have created a method which gets called when the button gets clicked. When I include the code for calling another class in this method it shows the above error & when I remove that code it neither shows the error nor goes ahead when listview etc. gets clicked. Can you please check my code and help me please.

CODE:

```
public void myClickHandler(View view)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "yesss",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
         ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);
         ListView FirstProjectActivity = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist1);
         FirstProjectActivity.setAdapter(adapter);

         Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstProjectActivity.this,
                 City.class);
        FirstProjectActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

         //startActivity(new Intent(FirstProjectActivity.this, City.class));
    }
```

LOGCAT is as follows:

```
  03-02 18:56:28.136: D/AndroidRuntime(316): Shutting down VM
03-02 18:56:28.136: W/dalvikvm(316): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.FirstProject/com.example.FirstProject.FirstProjectActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.example.FirstProject.FirstProjectActivity.onCreate(FirstProjectActivity.java:37)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-02 18:56:28.226: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  ... 11 more
03-02 18:56:35.396: I/Process(316): Sending signal. PID: 316 SIG: 9
03-02 19:02:51.836: D/AndroidRuntime(351): Shutting down VM
03-02 19:02:51.836: W/dalvikvm(351): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.FirstProject/com.example.FirstProject.FirstProjectActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.example.FirstProject.FirstProjectActivity.onCreate(FirstProjectActivity.java:37)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-02 19:02:51.866: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  ... 11 more
03-02 19:03:03.647: I/Process(351): Sending signal. PID: 351 SIG: 9
03-02 20:11:17.722: W/KeyCharacterMap(379): No keyboard for id 0
03-02 20:11:17.926: W/KeyCharacterMap(379): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
03-02 20:11:28.441: D/dalvikvm(379): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3121 objects / 172672 bytes in 1696ms
03-03 01:03:02.696: W/KeyCharacterMap(406): No keyboard for id 0
03-03 01:03:02.696: W/KeyCharacterMap(406): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
03-03 01:03:08.566: D/dalvikvm(406): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2874 objects / 162408 bytes in 192ms
03-03 01:33:06.566: D/AndroidRuntime(432): Shutting down VM
03-03 01:33:06.566: W/dalvikvm(432): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.example.FirstProject.FirstProjectActivity.myClickHandler(FirstProjectActivity.java:69)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  ... 11 more
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.FirstProject/com.example.FirstProject.City}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
03-03 01:33:06.726: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  ... 15 more
03-03 01:33:08.956: I/Process(432): Sending signal. PID: 432 SIG: 9
03-03 01:34:05.387: D/AndroidRuntime(460): Shutting down VM
03-03 01:34:05.387: W/dalvikvm(460): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at com.example.FirstProject.FirstProjectActivity.myClickHandler(FirstProjectActivity.java:70)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  ... 11 more
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.FirstProject/com.example.FirstProject.City}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
03-03 01:34:05.417: E/AndroidRuntime(460):  ... 15 more
03-03 01:34:11.016: I/Process(460): Sending signal. PID: 460 SIG: 9
03-03 01:35:33.547: D/AndroidRuntime(490): Shutting down VM
03-03 01:35:33.557: W/dalvikvm(490): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at com.example.FirstProject.FirstProjectActivity.myClickHandler(FirstProjectActivity.java:70)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  ... 11 more
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.FirstProject/com.example.FirstProject.City}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
03-03 01:35:33.577: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  ... 15 more
03-03 01:35:39.176: I/Process(490): Sending signal. PID: 490 SIG: 9
03-03 01:36:06.947: D/AndroidRuntime(517): Shutting down VM
03-03 01:36:06.947: W/dalvikvm(517): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.FirstProject.FirstProjectActivity.myClickHandler(FirstProjectActivity.java:70)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  ... 11 more
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.FirstProject/com.example.FirstProject.City}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
03-03 01:36:06.967: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  ... 15 more
03-03 01:36:13.306: I/Process(517): Sending signal. PID: 517 SIG: 9
```

Comment: when i click that button list gets displayed but after that when i clicks on list item nothing happens.So i think that class to display list is not executing and i wrote the code in that method to call that class using intent as shown above but it started giving an error "application has stopped unexpectedly,please try again"..please people help me.

Comment: What does the logcat error say? What exception was thrown?

Comment: hey Benoir,can u tell me,i hav created a class to display list and i want to call that class from my default class(generated while creating project)when i click on list item of previous screen. i hav written the method for on click event of list but when i click on the list item of first list then nothing happens whereas it should display next list on next screen.code for onclick event of first list item is as follows:

Comment: public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, List.class);
         Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
         intent.putExtra("tn", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
         startActivity(intent);
     }

Comment: below is the logcat..please help me to solve problem "application has stopped unexpectedly,please try again"...LOGCAT:

Comment: i have posted logcat above..please help me to solve problem "application has stopped unexpectedly,please try again"

Answer (score 0):

When you want to detect if you click on an item you need to implement the onItemClickedListener i will give you an example below like i would do it:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new MyOnitemClickListener());
//no i make my own class that impelemnts the onitemclicklistener
public class MyOnitemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
        private int position = 0;

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                long lat) {
             // clicked on parent.getid()
             if (parent.getId() == R.id.listView) {
            //do something
         } 

    }
}
```

Comment: bt friend,it's not the list i am talking about button when i click that button list gets displayed but after that when i clicks on list item nothing happens.So i think that class to display list is not executing and i wrote the code in that method to call that class using intent as shown above but it started giving an error "application has stopped unexpectedly,please try again".

Answer (score 0):

after a crash, try looking for the first couple of red lines the LOGCAT spews to you as they usually explain what happened.

the following line :

> java.lang.NullPointerException

(in line 5) showed up on you log, it usually means your trying to use an uninitialized object.

refer to:

[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)